# Write Ruby Test::Unit Errors & Fails to File

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, stdout, stderr, testunit

I am trying to write fails and errors that occur in the test to a log file, so that they don't appear on-screen, but it appears as though errors and assert failures write to STDOUT instead of STDERR. I have been unable to find information on how to redirect this output after hours of googling, and would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Do you have a special logging, or do you mean the regular output? You could start your test script and redirect on OS-level. Example: 'mytests.rb > log.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should the errors not be on stdout?
Up to now I have no prepared solution to suppress the output for specific errors.

If you accept the unchanged output, I have a solution to store errors and failures in a file. It will be no problem to create a 2nd file for Notifications...

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

module Test
  module Unit
    class TestSuite
      alias :old_run :run
      def run(result, &progress_block)
        old_run(result, &progress_block)
        File.open('test.log', 'w'){|f|
          result.faults.each{|err|
            case err
              when Test::Unit::Error, Test::Unit::Failure
                f << err.long_display
                f << "\n===========\n"
              #not in log file
              when Test::Unit::Pending, Test::Unit::Notification, Test::Unit::Omission
              end
          }
        }
      end
    end
  end
end


class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_1()
    assert_equal( 3, 1+1) #failure
  end
  def test_2()
    1 / 0 #force an error
  end
  def test_3()
    notify 'sss'
  end
  def test_4()
    pend "MeineKlasse.new"
  end
  def test_5
    omit 'aaa' if RUBY_VERSION == '1.9.2'
  end

  def test_5
    assert_in_delta( 0.1, 0.00001, 1.0/10)
  end

end
```

Comment: THANK YOU! THIS is what I was looking for. I figured there must be some way to change the handling of the Test::Unit failures and errors but I couldn't find any reference to it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried redirecting the output to StringIO, to write it to a logfile later?

```
original_stdout = $stdout
original_stderr = $stderr
fake_stdout = StringIO.new
fake_stderr = StringIO.new

$stdout = fake_stdout
$stderr = fake_stderr
```

Then after you've ran the tests:

```
$stdout = original_stdout
$stderr = original_stderr

@stdout = fake_stdout.string
@stderr = fake_stderr.string
```

I'm not really sure this will work though...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this!  I ran into some `test/unit` testcases that had been doing something like this behind my back, plus it was using the `fakefs` gem, so writing to a logfile was out (also when I tried the `debugger` gem, it did not work presumably since stderr & stdout were faked).  Was pulling my hair out before I realized I could simply do: `STDOUT.puts 'hello world'`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood yor question correct.

Do you mean something like this:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

class StdOutLogger < IO
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @file = File.open('log.txt', 'w')
    @stdout = true
  end 
  #write to stdout and file
  def write(s)
    $stdout << s
    @file << s
  end
end
STDOUT = StdOutLogger.new(1)

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase      
  def test_1()
    assert_equal( 2, 1+1)
    assert_equal( 2, 4/2)

    assert_equal( 1, 3/2)
    assert_equal( 1.5, 3/2.0)
  end
end
```

But I would recommend to copy stdout on operation system level

```
ruby mytest.rb > log.txt
```

---

Here is a version to skip between stdout and file output. The output switch is only a  interim solution - perhaps it can be made better.

```
class StdOutLogger < IO
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @file = File.open('log.txt', 'w')
    @stdout = true
  end 
  def write(s)
    case s
      when /\AError:/
        @stdout = false #change to file
      when /\A(Pending):/
        @stdout = true #change to file
    end

    if @stdout
    $stdout << s
    else
    @file << s
    end
  end
end
STDOUT = StdOutLogger.new(1)
```

Comment: That is one solution (and also applies to @user899435), the problem is that it leaves NOTHING on-screen. I'd like to limit the log file to only failures and errors but leave everything else. I've also tried redirecting STDOUT to a file right before a batch of assertions and switching it back to the old STDOUT after the assertions, but if there are any errors or failures, then the test exits and STDOUT is never changed back.

Comment: I modified my answer to allow a simultaneous output to stdout and File. At the end of my answer is a version, where I switch between stdout and File. It worked in an example, but I'm sure, it must be adapted.  I would prefer a solution where you write (or duplicate) stdout to a file and you prepare a post process. -- and I'm working at another idea - more details will follow.

Comment: I posted my other solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098963/write-ruby-testunit-errors-fails-to-file/7099264#7099264 - seems to be the right solutuion ;)